# rspec factorygirl build a factory of variable list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot

I have a factory for a response object that contains a list, so I have a factory for that list as well, but I am now trying to get dynamic list every time I make the build_list call.

Current state of the world is below:

An API call and response that looks something like this.

```
pry(main)> get_customer('12345').class
=> Com::ListResult
pry(main)> get_customer('12345').c_list.class
=> Array
pry(main)> get_customer('12345').c_list[0].class
=> Com::Customer`
```

Output of the call:

```
pry(main)> get_customer('12345')
=> #<Com::ListResult:0xHEX
  @c_list=
   [#<Com::Customer:0xHEX
     @account_id="12345",
     @email="test@bla.com">]>
```

I have created a factory and it works fine if I want to make the `get_customer` call just once.
Here how the factory is setup:

```
factory :customer_each, class: Com::Customer do
  account_id "12345"
  email "test@bla.com"
end
factory :customer_list_result, class: Com::ListResult do
  customer_list FactoryGirl.build_list(:customer_each, 1)
end
```

In the rspec, I have below to get me the mock results.

```
allow(subject).to receive(:get_customer).and_return(build(:customer_list_result))
```

Now I am trying to get different list every time I make the mock call. I tried sequence as shown below expecting account_id to be 11111, 22222, and so on but I always get 11111 back. Email doesn't matter since I only want a variable account_id.

```
  factory :customer_bulk, class: Com::Customer do
    sequence(:account_id) {|n| "#{n}"*5}
    email "test@bla.com"
  end
  factory :customer_list_result, class: Com::ListResult do
    customer_list FactoryGirl.build_list(:customer_bulk, 1)
  end
```

Comment: Try `customer_list { FactoryGirl.build_list(:customer_bulk, 1) }`. The braces cause FactoryGirl to re-evaluate what's inside. For example, to get random numbers, you use `attribute { rand(0..10) }` instead of `attribute rand(0..10)`.

Comment: That did not work

Answer (score 0):

The sequence will bump the value by 1 for each factory method invocation in the *same* test. If you call it once, it'll only give you back the first sequence number, which in this case is `1`.

Would it be enough to just pass a random number as `account_id` every time you call the factory?

```
factory :customer_bulk, class: Com::Customer do
  # random 5-digit string
  account_id { rand(1e4...1e5).to_i.to_s }
  # or random string with same digit
  account_id { "#{rand(10).to_s}" * 5 }
end
```

Comment: Although I want to be able to have a sequential increment in the id, to be predictable, I went ahead and tried this just to rule out me not typing the sequence code correctly but I am still getting the same value returned every time.

Comment: I think I missed the brackets "{}" around the values. I'm sorry. Please try
`account_id { rand(1e4..1e5).to_i.to_s }`.
My initial answer will generate the random number _once_, at the time the code is parsed.

Comment: Thanks for the quick update. still the same result. I am not sure if build_list is actually building the factory again.

Comment: Why don't you try to use the factory outside of the other factory at first, to make sure that it indeed works?

It's hard to know your whole setup unfortunately, but in general I think what you're trying to achieve would be more cleanly solved by pure Ruby instead of factories inside factories.

What I mean of course is that you can keep your factories simple and compose (mix and match) them on each test. If you see room for re-usability consider creating helper methods in a module or class.

Comment: Ok that did not work as well. Now I am starting to think that the way I am returning the mock object is the issue? Could this be the issue?
 Is rspec adding some caching smarts somewhere? `allow(subject).to receive(:get_customer).and_return(build(:customer_list_result))`

Comment: I'm not sure about that sorry. It's been a while since I used Rspec. Try using the `allow_any_instance_of` method (or something like that). It might be overkill but it will probably ensure any instance of your class will get the mocked result. 
Try to keep your tests simple. If it's come down to mocking at this level, it probably means there's a simpler way to wire things up. ;)

Comment: I agree, that this needs to be simplified but I was just trying to preserve the object that I get back from the actual call. That being said I was able to simplify a bit and can get away with `allow(subject).to receive(:get_customer).and_return(build(:customer_bulk))` . But still sequence or random is not working

Comment: OK it works with `allow(subject).to receive(:get_customer).and_return(build(:customer_bulk), build(:customer_bulk))` It solves the purpose since I am only testing on 2 values but this is not clean at all.

Comment: meh.. http://owowthathurts.blogspot.com/2014/08/rspec-3-and-deprecated-andreturn-blocks.html .   `allow(subject).to receive(:get_customer) { (build(:customer_bulk)) }` fixed it.. Thanks for the pointers gkats

Comment: No problem! Happy if I helped.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, just had to change the rspec to return a block.

`allow(subject).to receive(:get_customer) { (build(:customer_bulk)) }`